# Java Client/Server App will not readLine()

Tags: java, client-server, client, server

I am trying to write a program that allows the user to send a message to a server and receive a modified version of that message. For some reason, the flow of the program stops on a certain line below, which I have pointed out. Can anybody explain why this isn't working? Thanks.

Server Side

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Server{

    public final static int port = 1025; 

    public static void main (String[] args){

        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket client;
        PrintWriter output;

        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            try{
                while(true){
                    client = serverSocket.accept();
                    InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String message = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Message received from client is " + message);

                    String returnMessage = message + message;

                    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                    bw.write(returnMessage);
                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + returnMessage);
                    bw.flush();
                }
            } catch(IOException e){ 
                serverSocket.close();
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Side

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Client{

    public void getService(String destination, int port){
        try{
            while(true)
            {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Send a message to the server: ");
                String message = in.nextLine();


                Socket server = new Socket(destination, port);

                OutputStream os = server.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);


                String sendMessage = message + "\n";
                bw.write(sendMessage);
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+ sendMessage);


                InputStream is = server.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String message2 = br.readLine(); // I have determined that the program's flow proceeds no further than this line
                System.out.println("Message received from the server : " + message2);

            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String serverAddress = args[0];
        System.out.println(serverAddress);

        Client client = new Client();
        client.getService(serverAddress, 1025);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server uses a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), whose `readLine` method requires an end of line delimiter, but the Client is not sending it - rather, it reads the line (with end of line delimiter stripped) and attempts to echo this message. Append a new line character to the data sent by the client so that the `readLine` method of the Server does not block while waiting for the line:

```
String returnMessage = message + message + "\n";
```